# Random Array Error

Tags: java

Why does the program show java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11?
The program needs to print 11 numbers. 9 numbers should be random.
It prints 11 numbers but it has an error.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random  = new Random();
        int[] Cnum = new int[11];
        Cnum[0]=0;
        Cnum[1]=9;
        System.out.print(Cnum[0]);
        System.out.print(Cnum[1]);

        for(int a = 2; 2 < 10; a++){
            Cnum[a]=random.nextInt(9);
            System.out.print(Cnum[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be (x is random) :

```
09xxxxxxxxx
```

But the output it does is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at CellphoneNumberGenerator.Main.main(Main.java:17)
    09505423220
```

Comment: `for(int a=2;2<10;a++){` has a typo in the condition, making it evaluate to const true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int a=2;2<10;a++)
```

That is basically a `while(True)` (infinite) loop because 2 is always less than 10. Perhaps you meant:

```
for(int a= 2; a<10; a++)
```

Answer (score 4):

In your for cycle the condition is wrong.

You have `2 < 10` instead of `a < 10`